# Problem with react-pdf library, when using usePDF hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-pdf

I use usePDF hook to download rendered pdf file, and it works correctly, but when i move to another page and come back to pdf page, button stops working. I check instance after returning from another page and blob file in it becomes null

```
const [instance, updateInstance] = usePDF({ document: ShowPdf() }) // ShowPdf is a function that returns <document>...pdf content</document>
```

How can I fix this problem?
My library
https://react-pdf.org/

This is my instance before moving to another page/component
[image]

This is after returning from another page/component
[image]

Comment: I have the same issue, did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Instantiating component as JSX component worked for me -

```
const [instance, updateInstance] = usePDF({ document: <ShowPdf/> })
```

Answer (score 0):

this issue resole from
https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/issues/1696#issuecomment-1229845402

`import { pdf } from "@react-pdf/renderer";`

or use component PDFDownloadLink
https://react-pdf.org/components#pdfdownloadlink